# Why does this return true true and not stack overflow?

Tags: java, recursion, boolean-logic

Why isn't this an infinite recursive loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isSuch(99) + " " + isSuch(100));
    }

    public static boolean isSuch(int n)
   {
      System.out.println("n is currently at "+ n);
       return n > 2 && !isSuch(n - 2);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an infinite recursive loop, because it will eventually stop.  It stops because the `&&` operator is a *short-circuiting operator*.  The [JLS, Section 15.23](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23), describes the `&&` operator:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

When the recursion reaches a level where `n` is not greater than `2`, then the `&&` operator immediately returns `false` *without* evaluating the right hand side, which is the recursive call.  That effectively makes the case where `n` is not greater than `2` the base case.  Then previous recursive calls invert it with the `!` operator, returning `true`.  Both calls return `true`, and `true` is printed twice.

It is worth noting that while this is a pretty deep recursion, the stack size was more than enough to handle this.  But it's not necessary to be an infinitely recursing loop for a `StackOverflowError` to occur.  All it needs is to recurse far enough.  Calling `isSuch(99999)` is enough to cause a `StackOverflowError` on my box.

Also, if you had used the non-short-circuiting operator `&` instead of `&&`, then it would be an infinitely recursive loop, and a `StackOverflowError` would occur regardless of what number was originally passed to `isSuch`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Short-Circuit Logical Operators**
>
> The **OR** operator results in true when first operand is true, no
>   matter what the second operand is. The **AND** operator results in
>   false when first operand is false, no matter what the second operand
>   is. If you use the **||** and **&&,** Java will not evaluate the
>   right-hand operand when the outcome can be determined by the left
>   operand alone.

In your sample code when value of n becomes equal to 2, condition 
**`**n > 2 && !isSuch(n - 2)**`** immediately becomes false since first operand is false, so next operand will not be evaluated thus isSuch() method will not be called.